# JsDOC - documenting object literals whose values are functions

Tags: javascript, types, jsdoc

Let's say I have an object that looks like this:

```
var scripts = {
    'common': {
        init: function() {        

        },
        finalize: function() {

        }
    },
    'home': {
        init: function() {

        },
        finalize: function() {

        }
    },
};
```

How can I define this object's type?

I defined the object's type in two steps:

1) Defined the inner object's type (the one with init: and finalize:) like soL

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ScriptTriggerSequence
 * @property {function} init
 * @property {function} finalize
 */
```

2) Then created the type for the whole object:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, ScriptTriggerSequence>} ScriptOrchestrationDefinition
 */
```

However, I'm not sure if I can write this: `@property {function} init`. There isn't a buil-in "function" type so this does not look good to me.

How can I describe a an object whose keys are strings and values are function like in the example above?